# MongoDB Connectivity Problems

Tags: mongodb

Is there any issue with MongoDB connections? I get the following error when I tried to connect to my local running MongoDB instance:

```
QUERY    Error: 'createUser' command not found.  This is most likely because you are talking to an old (pre v2.6) MongoDB server
```

Here is the console lines when I start MongoDB!

```
My-MacBook-Pro:Projects joe$ mongod --dbpath /Users/joe/Projects/my-data
Wed Oct 21 19:53:21 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=974 port=27017 dbpath=/Users/joe/Projects/my-data 64-bit host=My-MacBook-Pro.local
Wed Oct 21 19:53:21 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.6, pdfile version 4.5
Wed Oct 21 19:53:21 [initandlisten] git version: e1c0cbc25863f6356aa4e31375add7bb49fb05bc
Wed Oct 21 19:53:21 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin erh2.10gen.cc 9.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 9.8.0: Wed Jul 15 16:55:01 PDT 2009; root:xnu-1228.15.4~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_40
Wed Oct 21 19:53:21 [initandlisten] options: { dbpath: "/Users/joe/Projects/inland24-data" }
Wed Oct 21 19:53:21 [initandlisten] journal dir=/Users/joe/Projects/inland24-data/journal
Wed Oct 21 19:53:21 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Wed Oct 21 19:53:21 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Wed Oct 21 19:53:21 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Wed Oct 21 19:54:21 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:14 virt:2432 mapped:0
Wed Oct 21 19:57:27 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50171 #1
Wed Oct 21 19:59:21 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:15 virt:2432 mapped:0
```

I don't know from where the db version is 2.0.6 which is strange! I later realized that it was an old MongoDB instance that I created using brew. I managed to get rid of it and now I see that MongoDB 3.0.6 is being used!

So, now I'm hitting the second problem, which is connecting to the database:

```
2015-10-21T20:55:25.664+0200 I ACCESS   [conn2] Failed to authenticate joe@mydb with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed UserNotFound Could not find user joe@mydb
2015-10-21T20:55:25.673+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52134 #11 (11 connections now open)
```

Comment: Well I think what is happening is what it is saying. Log into your DB via the shell as an admin. from there do `db.getUsers();` and see if that user is there

Comment: The user exists! I verified it!

Comment: you have some roles assigned to that user or a password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your [authentication method](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/#authentication-mechanisms)  from [MONGODB-CR](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/#authentication-mongodb-cr), to  [SCRAM-SHA-1](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/#authentication-scram-sha-1):

[`mongod --setParameter authenticationMechanisms=PLAIN --auth`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/#param.authenticationMechanisms)